# How to pass Windows Messages from one thread to another?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm writing a console game engine. Game loop in it is handled in a separate thread function:

```
hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        &_GameThread,
        _self,
        0,
        &dwThreadID);

WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
```

`_GameThread()` itself contains just a simple `while(1)` for now. Pretty straightforward.

I need to somehow manage controls in the game, so I chose approach of making a message window, which translates buttons pressed to some array, which is then processed by functions within thread to some action(movement, turning, etc.). Also made a function, which passes the message to a hidden window:

```
int _DispMessage()
{
    MSG msg;
    int gResult;
    if(gResult = GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return gResult;
}
```

Without thread this function works fine, but when game loop comes out, no message is received from within, except for creation messages. So the question is: How to make messages asynchronous, so I could push keycodes into a queue and then retrieve them inside game loop?

I have only main process, which executes the engine and one thread.

Comment: A better approach is not to use messages, but synchronization priminities (events etc).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I can use mutex or event, but controls themself won't trigger, I need to somehow manage keypresses, so they will be continuous and no heavy cycles inside game loop could slow things down, and the controls themself won't hold thread

Comment: PostMessage() the key messages to the other thread and retrieve them there with another getMessage loop.

Comment: @MartinJames the main problem is, it doesn't catch any messages within thead. I do a PeekMessage loop, which does not hold thread if there is no message, but there aren't a single

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov UI windows have *thread affinity*. Only the thread that creates a window can receive messages for that window. To do what you are asking, you will need to create a (hidden) window in your game thread so you can then post/send messages to that window using `(Post|Send)Message()`.  Or, post messages to the thread itself using `PostThreadMessage()`.

Answer (score 0):

That is a classic [Producer-Consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). You can look it up online for examples of implementation.

The basic idea is to have an array of shared memory between the main thread and the thread that will consume your keycode.

When the main thread access the array (that is when you read a keycode), you lock the array using a mutex or a semaphore. When the key has been added to the array, the lock is released.

On the consumer thread, before trying to access the array, you wait for the semaphore/mutex to be unlocked, you lock it, consume the key from it, and then release the lock.

Take note that this solution as it stands will be slower (in term of performance) than managing the keys from the main thread. When you lock a thread, it essentially stop working until you unlock it. So if your consumer thread is not doing work apart than waiting for the main thread, the cost of locking/unlocking, switching contexts, etc, will be add overhead to the program.